# Shannon formula for channel capacity

Tags: channel

Shannon formula for channel capacity states that
$$C=\log\left(1+\frac{S}{N}\right)$$
If this formula applied for baseband transmission only? Is it applied with passband transmission?
Are there any changes in the formula with different types of modulation, for example, OFDM??

Comment: As a side note: it seems like you could really benefit from getting a few good textbooks and reading them. This site is not really a good replacement for taking courses or focused self-study. Let me know if you need book recommendations.

Comment: Forgot the channel bandwidth?

Comment: @Gilles in this version the units are bits per second per Hertz. Sometimes it is called spectral efficiency, multiplication by the bandwidth gives you bits per second

Comment: @Engineer I'm more used to this $C = B\log_2 \left(1 + \frac SN\right)$, or when it is the spectral efficiency then $\eta$ is used.

Comment: i think it's missing the $B$. and it should be base 2 logarithm. an even more general form is when $S$ and $N$ are not constant with frequency:

$$ C = \int\limits_0^B \log_2\left(1 + \frac{S(f)}{N(f)} \right) \ \mathrm{d}f $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula is for baseband with real symbols in an AWGN channel.

However, it is trivially easy to adjust it for quadrature modulation or complex symbols: just double the capacity.

OFDM and other wideband modulations operate over frequency-selective channels, which have different capacity. There are capacity formulas for many channels in the literature.